# Error when I try to invoke Phaser.Group.create() in other functions

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm making a magic tower using Phaser-framework,here is my test floor:
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsFow.png)

here are my codes,now I try to use Doors to replace yellowDoors,blueDoors,redDoors.

```
Doors = game.add.group(); 
yellowDoors = game.add.group();
function createWithColor(group, color, x, y, key, frame) { 
    var child = group.create(x, y, key, frame);
    child.color = color;
}
```

when I use this line,the yellow Door was added to the center of the picture normally:[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFtsx.png)

```
yellowDoors.create(5*32,5*32,'doors',0);
```

but things get abnormal when using this line,the image would turn to the same as the first picture:

`createWithColor(Doors, 0, 5 * 32, 5 * 32, 'doors', 0);`

the target of function "createWithColor" is to create a group named **Doors**,instead of producing three groups:yellowDoors,blueDoors,redDoors;the problem has puzzled me for more than an hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I add Doors to the group first,then the ground.

```
Doors = game.add.group();
...
ground = game.add.group();
```

in Phaser,things are always added to the top of the group
so,the ground covers the Doors,make it invisible